# JS array failing when multiple variables included

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tidying some code that looks at the value of a cookie called 'region' before settings it's own cookie:

```
if(regionvalue.indexOf("foo")>=0){
        Cookies.set('local-council', 1);
}
if(regionvalue.indexOf("foo2")>=0){
        Cookies.set('local-council', 1);
}
```

In the above example, if the value is 'foo' or 'foo2' I want the same 'local-council' cookie to be created.

This code works but isn't well structured. I want to use an array to tidy things up:

```
var multiregion = ['foo1', 'foo2'];
if(regionvalue.indexOf(multiregion)>=0){
        Cookies.set('local-council', 1);
}
```

Unfortunately, the above array isn't working. However, the 'local-council' cookie is created if only one variable e.g. 'foo1' is specified.

There doesn't look to be any syntax errors and the browser's console isn't showing any issues. I'm confused as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Why? Because `Array#indexOf()` only works for full match. It's not the same as `String#indexOf()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order

```
var multiregion = ['foo1', 'foo2'];
if(multiregion.indexOf(regionvalue) >= 0){
    Cookies.set('local-council', 1);
}
```

or using es6 `includes()`

```
var multiregion = ['foo1', 'foo2'];
if(multiregion.includes(regionvalue)){
    Cookies.set('local-council', 1);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work but reading the comment by @charlietfl provided the results I wanted. I was only adding in part of the cookies value, not the whole thing. This woked with Array#indexOf() but not String#indexOf() as he mentioned. I'm now using your es6 code with the complete cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for that:

```js
const multiregion = ['foo1', 'foo2'];
const regionvalue = 'foo1';
if(multiregion.some(i => regionvalue.indexOf(i) >= 0)){
        document.write('works');
}
```